how to activate key press functions on smartphone or tablet
When exploring the web, there are sometimes little applications, written in js or so, that use key-press input to execute some functions, and this has nothing to do with a text-input-field like the ones used to write posts here.
Sample:
P5js Hyperbolic painting tool
Some functions of this, like switching the painting mode or toggle or change properties are handled by pressing a key on the keyboard.
On a PC this works fine, because i use the the real physical Keyboard for this.
But how can i use key-press-input without textfield, when i use a smartphone or tablet, that has only the screen-keyboard, that only pops up when selecting a textfield?
Is there any way to force the screen-keyboard without having a textfield?
